# Windows file explorer won't preview PDF: "the file you are attempting to preview could harm your computer"

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, preview

Some pdfs view fine... others have this message:
 "the file you are attempting to preview could harm your computer..."
Is there a reason for this happening?

Comment: Reproduced on Windows 7 with Acrobat X Standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shortening the filename path fixed it for me!

(Couldn't find this anywhere on the net, then noticed shorter filenames previewed fine... thought I'd share it.  MS had fun with this error message. :-)

Click the upvote if it works for you! :)